# change button color on button click in main form and remains that button color even on form that inherited main form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, colors

[image: two forms with inherited buttons]

I have two forms. One is Main form and another one is form2 that inherited main form.
I change button color on button click event on main form and want that color changed button on form2.
The problem here is change button color on main form but not on form2. Send Help Pls.

Here's is my code .
//Form1 Main Form

```
namespace BtnColor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private Button btn = null;
        protected void BtnSetting(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            button.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(151, 242, 0);
            if(btn != null)
            {
                btn.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
            }
            btn = button;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnSetting(button1, null);
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnSetting(button2, null);
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.Show();
            
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}

//Form 2
namespace BtnColor
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form1
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens on/in form1 stays in form1.  Inheritance doesnt include historical user actions.  You could always mirror such actions via *code*

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on the excellent comment by Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp, form inheritance is more of a design-time behavior where the subclass inherits the *layout* properties you specify. But at runtime, when you make a instance of `InheritedClass`, its instance of (for example) `buttonSetting` is distinct as well.

So to "mirror" the color change behavior, add a handler for when `buttonSetting.BackColor` changes and go through all of the forms in the app to synchronize the change.

```
buttonSetting.BackColorChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (
        sender is Button srce
        &&
        string.Equals(srce.Name, "buttonSetting"))
    {
        foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainForm>())
        {
            // Find the button on each form and update its color.
            if (form.Controls["buttonSetting"] is Button dest)
            {
                dest.BackColor = srce.BackColor;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

###### Example

Here's that snippet with some context:

[image: demo showing synchronized color changes]

###### Inherited Form Class

```
public class InheritedForm : MainForm 
{
    public InheritedForm()
    {
        var richTextBox = new RichTextBox
        {
            Size = new Size(230, 220),
            Location = new Point(237, 12),
            Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xF,
        };
        richTextBox.SelectionIndent = 10;
        richTextBox.AppendText($"Inherited forms only.{Environment.NewLine}");
        Controls.Add(richTextBox);
        foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if(sender is Button button) 
                {
                    richTextBox.AppendText($"{button.Text} Clicked!");
                }
            };
        }
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CloseReason.Equals(CloseReason.UserClosing))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Hide();
            Application.OpenForms["MainForm"]?.BringToFront(); // Workaroud 'last visible child' issue
        }
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

---

###### MainForm runtime

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonSetting.BackColorChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (
                sender is Button srce
                &&
                string.Equals(srce.Name, "buttonSetting"))
            {
                foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainForm>())
                {
                    // Find the button on each form and update its color.
                    if (form.Controls["buttonSetting"] is Button dest)
                    {
                        dest.BackColor = srce.BackColor;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Toggle color
        buttonSetting.Click += (sender, e) =>
            buttonSetting.BackColor = buttonSetting.BackColor.Equals(Color.LightSkyBlue) ?
            Color.FromArgb(151, 242, 0) : Color.LightSkyBlue;

        buttonShowForm1.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var mainForm = Application.OpenForms["MainForm"];
            if (Application.OpenForms["f1"] is Form form)                   
            {
                if(!form.Visible) form.Show(mainForm);
            }
            else
            {
                new InheritedForm
                {
                    Text = "Inherited Form 1",
                    Name = "f1",
                    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                    Size = mainForm.Size,
                    Location = new Point(mainForm.Left + mainForm.Width + 10, mainForm.Top),
                }.Show(mainForm);
            }
        };
        buttonShowForm2.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var mainForm = Application.OpenForms["MainForm"];
            if (Application.OpenForms["f2"] is Form form)
            {
                if (!form.Visible) form.Show(mainForm);
            }
            else
            {
                new InheritedForm
                { 
                    Text = "Inherited Form 2",
                    Name = "f2",
                    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                    Size = mainForm.Size,
                    Location = new Point(
                        mainForm.Left + mainForm.Width + 10, 
                        mainForm.Top + mainForm.Height + 10),
                }.Show(mainForm);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/synchronized-button.git)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. my question solves with changing color in derived form constructor .